# Reading or writing xml file in MASM32 SDK

Tags: xml, winapi, masm32

Is there any way in MASM32 SDK to read or write XML file?
I can not found any windows API for XML.

Comment: What's wrong with a high level language? There is MSXML but it's going to be hell from masm.

Comment: Why on earth would there be an XML parser in Win32? Find or write your own!

Comment: @David: [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742.aspx) exposes it's services through COM. As such it's no more complicated to access from assembly than any other C interface.

Comment: @IInspectable Well, I think MSXML is quite a meaty interface. I would not fancy it from masm.

Comment: @David: Accessing COM from assembly may be overly verbose and tedious, however, it is straight forward. In the end it's all just pointers to interfaces, where 'members' are invoked through indirect calls. If developer efficiency is required, then writing an RAII infrastructure in C++ increases productivity tenfold, easily. Going with MASM, I doubt that this is desired. I wouldn't want to do it either, but if someone else does, it's not terribly complicated to do.